# Verify $\frac{a_{20}}{a_{20}+b_{20}}$ in Mathematica, May help me?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion, code-request

The solution of $\frac{a_{20}}{a_{20}+b_{20}}$ is $-39$ from the recursive system of equations :

\begin{cases}
a_{n+1}=-2a_n-4b_n  \\
b_{n+1}=4a_n+6b_n\\
a_0=1,b_0=0
\end{cases}

This is taken from $2007$ GATE entrance exam in **India**.

> How I can check or verify this solution that comes from 2007-GATE Exam
>   with Mathematica? Is there any toolbox in this software that can
>   calculated about the above equation? (at least can I see this code online, I didn't have this software)?

Comment: Is there a typo? Seems like the answer could only be 1/2 (or undefined).

Comment: Here's how I would check that:  `#1/(#1 + #1) & @@@ 
 RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == -2 a[n - 1] - 4 b[n - 1], 
   b[n] == 4 a[n - 1] + 6 b[n - 1], a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1}, {a, b}, {n,
    0, 20}]` and it gives $1/2$ for all $n$

Comment: Try `MatrixPower[{{-2, -4}, {4, 6}}, 20, {1, 0}]`.

Comment: Not always, but glad to help. :)

Comment: Look up [`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html), as @JasonB mentioned.

Comment: `RSolve[{a[n + 1] == -2 a[n] - 4 b[n], b[n + 1] == 4 a[n] + 6 b[n], 
  a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1}, {a[n], b[n]}, n]` yields `{{a[n] -> -2^n (-1 + 4 n), b[n] -> 2^n (1 + 4 n)}}`, then `Simplify[(-2^n (-1 + 4 n))/(- 2^n (-1 + 4 n) + 2^n (1 + 4 n))]` yields `1/2 - 2 n`, i.e. for  `n==20` it should be `-79/2`, not `-39`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor change from @JasonB (not taking credit for this one).

```
#1/(#1 + #2) & @@@RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == -2 a[n - 1] - 4 b[n - 1], 
  b[n] == 4 a[n - 1] + 6 b[n - 1], a[0] == 1, b[0] == 0}, {a, b}, {n, 
  0, 20}]
```

> {1, -1, -3, -5, -7, -9, -11, -13, -15, -17, -19, -21, -23, -25, -27, 
>   -29, -31, -33, -35, -37, **-39**}

[image]

Comment: @user355834 I guess,...
You can also go here:   http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%231%2F(%231+%2B+%232)+%26+@@@RecurrenceTable%5B%7Ba%5Bn%5D+%3D%3D+-2+a%5Bn+-+1%5D+-+4+b%5Bn+-+1%5D,+b%5Bn%5D+%3D%3D+4+a%5Bn+-+1%5D+%2B+6+b%5Bn+-+1%5D,+a%5B0%5D+%3D%3D+1,+b%5B0%5D+%3D%3D+0%7D,+%7Ba,+b%7D,+%7Bn,+0,+20%7D%5D

Answer (score 5):

Or using [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear[a, b];

{a[n_], b[n_]} = {a[n], b[n]} /. RSolve[{
     a[n + 1] == -2 a[n] - 4 b[n],
     b[n + 1] == 4 a[n] + 6 b[n],
     a[0] == 1, b[0] == 0}, {a[n], b[n]}, n][[1]]

(*  {-2^n (-1 + 2 n), 2^(1 + n) n}  *)

f[n_] = a[n]/(a[n] + b[n]) // Simplify

(*  1 - 2 n  *)

f[20]

(*  -39  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to solve this. Start with

```
a[20]/(a[20]+b[20])
```

and apply the recurrence a few times leading to

```
-(a[19]+2b[19])/(a[19]+b[19]),-(3a[18]+4b[18])/(a[18]+b[18]),(5a[17]+6b[17])/(a[17]+b[17])
```

The pattern is clear. Twenty applications results in

```
-(39a[0]+40b[0])/(a[0]+b[0])
```

and applying the initial condition gives you the result.

Comment: So, how does one use *Mathematica* to automate your procedure? :)

Comment: Use Nest to iterate the replacement rules 20 times and then apply the initial condition: `Nest[Function[f, Factor[f /. {a[n_] -> -2a[n - 1] - 4b[n - 1], b[n_] -> 4a[n - 1] + 6b[n - 1]}]], a[20]/(a[20] + b[20]), 20] /. {a[0] -> 1, b[0] -> 0}`. Factor is used to prevent intermediate expression swell.